# Wrong status after updating from 7.64 to 7.66

Tags: 7, updating

I recently manually updated my localhost drupal site from 7.64 to 7.66.  I ran update.php without errors.  When the process finished, I cleared all cache and checked the status.  It still reported 7.64.  I then re-ran the manual update and got the same results.  When I look at system.info, I see:

```
; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2019-04-17
version = "7.66"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1555533576"
```

I've noticed other posts ([here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2013-04-05/version-number-doesnt-change) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2009-03-17/wrong-version-in-update-status)) on the Drupal site that report the same type of symptoms, but, no one has reported a valid solution to resolve this discrepancy.  Does anyone know how to get things back in sync?

**UPDATE**: As part of this process, I successfully updated two other sites I maintain to 7.66.  The glaring difference that I need explained is after running update.php on localhost, I do not see "Pending Update" as I did on the other two sites.

Comment: Maybe add your references too to help others find an answer?

Comment: `but, no one has reported a valid solution` cog.rusty [solved the issue](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2009-03-17/wrong-version-in-update-status#comment-1367712).

Comment: @NoSssweat - I saw that, but, it does not help me.  I think the key is why the update process does not see the pending update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the includes folder and add new includes folder from 7.66 version, `bootstrap.inc` defines the drupal version.

Comment: Thanks, but, I took a look at my existing `bootstrap.inc` and it defines version 7.66.